# Is my proof okay? If A is dense in B and B is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, then A is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

### Definition given for dense:

> Let $A\subset B$. We say that $A$ is dense in $B$ if $\forall a,b\in B, a<b, \exists x\in A \text{ such that }x\in (a,b).$

### Proof

Suppose that $A$ is dense in $B$ and $B$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b<c<d$.

Since $B$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, $\exists y,z\in B$ such that $y\in (a,b)$ and $z\in (c,d)$.

Since $A$ is dense in $B$, $\exists x\in A$ such that $x\in (y,z)$.

Because $y\in (a,b)$ and $z\in (c,d)$, $x\in (a,d)$.

Therefore $\forall a,d\in \mathbb{R}, \exists x\in A \text{ such that }x\in (a,d).$

So $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The proof looks good to me. (One minor quibble: the definition of "dense" should explicitly stipulate $a\lt b$.)

Comment: An important point - I'll edit the definition.

Comment: Yes. I second Barry Cipra's endorsement.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is essentially sound.  I will rip out my red pen over the way you dealt with quantified variables at the start, though.  You should only let $a,d\in\mathbb R$ be given such that $a<d$, since that's what the definition of a dense set requires.  You can then go on to say that you can ***choose*** $b,c\in\mathbb R$ such that $a<b<c<d$, since $\mathbb R$ is a continuum.  (Indeed, you can just come out and take $b:=a+\frac{d-a}3$ and $c:=d-\frac{d-a}3$.)

Without that, a reader might have the right to question whether your proof only works for two different real numbers that happen to have two extra real numbers strictly between them.  It's a question you can answer when it is raised, but your goal as a proof-writer is to write proofs that don't raise fair questions.

Everything after that is clear.  Nice argument!

Comment: You're not wrong, but this strikes me as a bit pedantic.